# Run function before including contents of file?

Tags: php

Currently, I'm including my HTML "view" like so:

```
include $path_to_view;
```

I would like to be able to run a function on the contents of the view file before I include it, but I'm not sure how to do that and still include the view without using eval:

I basically want to do an "include" type operation on the results of a function. Something like this:

```
include foo_function(file_get_contents($path_to_view));
```

How can I accomplish this, or is eval my only option?

**Edit**

I am using output buffers currently. I am not looking to change the view contents on disk, I just want to get the contents of the view, run a function on those contents, and "include" the contents so they are evaluated.

Comment: Well, if your $path_to_view contains HTML an include of the file would just concat its contents to the output. Effectively that's the same as saying "echo file_get_contents($path_to_view);". So to answer your question, you were almost there: "echo my_preprocessing_function(file_get_contents($path_to_view));" is plausible.

Comment: @Remco: That doesn't appear to cause the PHP to be in the view to be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for output buffering. Look at [`ob_start`](https://www.php.net/ob_start).

```
<?php

function callback($buffer)
{
  // Do something useful here.

  return $buffer;
}

ob_start('callback');

include $path_to_view;

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I still need to run a function over the contents of my view. I don't want to actually modify the view on disk, I just want to get the contents, run a function over them, and then "include" the contents so they are evaluated.

Comment: @TaylorOtwell - Using output buffering as in the example above, PHP will include your view and execute the PHP in it safely and the run the callback function. The `$buffer` variable contains the content of your view so that you can further process it. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: maybe.. what is the order of execution? I'm basically running some simple regexes to turn a "template" into plain PHP... I would need to run the callback before the contents of the output buffer are "evaluated" by PHP.

Comment: @TaylorOtwell - The `include` would execute execute first. What you're looking for is probably something like `file_get_contents($path_to_view)` to get the content, then call your function and finally, use `eval`. Be careful with `eval`.

Comment: @TaylorOtwell - I've created templates using `ob_start` and something similar to the example above. You can call `preg_replace('/abc/', '', $buffer);` and then `return $buffer;` to replace after the PHP have been executed...

Answer (score 0):

Look into output buffers. You can put the contents of a file into a var, then parse it as usual.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm using output buffers now... but I still have to "include" the contents of the file at some point so it is evaluated, which I am doing. I just want to be able run a function on the contents of that file before "including" it.

Comment: I think it would clarify a whole lot if you'd post a bit more of your code. I for one can't make out what you're meaning to say.